# php artisan make auth is not defined in laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

this is the first thing I did

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Result:

> ```
>   Command "make:auth" is not defined.
>
>   Did you mean one of these?
>       make:channel
>       make:command
>       make:controller
>       make:event
>       make:exception
>       make:factory
>       make:job
>       make:listener
>       make:mail
>       make:middleware
>       make:migration
>       make:model
>       make:notification
>       make:observer
>       make:policy
>       make:provider
>       make:request
>       make:resource
>       make:rule
>       make:seeder
>       make:test
> ```

2. the second one:

   php artisan ui vue --auth
   php artisan ui react --auth

I have tried this one, and here's the result

> ```
> The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/provider-2015%24e84cdb7b9b7175f18a814c1783741a3ba6b021c4a78701285cc5639d0d1ee4e6.json"
> ```
>
> file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed!
>
> ```
> http://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
> ```

---

what should I do? 
-thanks

Answer (score 6):

> What should I do?

Read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/frontend#introduction).

As of Laravel 6+, you'll need to install the separated UI package first in order to generate the Auth scaffolding:

```
composer require laravel/ui --dev
```

Just then you will be able to run one of the following:

```
// Generate basic scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap
php artisan ui vue
php artisan ui react

// Generate login / registration scaffolding...
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
php artisan ui vue --auth
php artisan ui react --auth
```

Comment: Highly appreciated, it works with Laravel 8.0 version. Thanks dear :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes in Laravel 6 auth scaffolding separated you can install it from composer

```
composer require laravel/ui
```